# How to handle multiple submit buttons using mootools?

Tags: mootools

In prototype you can use the following code.

```
 var form = control.form;
    new Ajax.Updater('result', form.action,
      { method: 'post',
        parameters: form.serialize({submit: control.name})
      }
    );

    return false;
```

Is there something like this in mootools? Simple but elegant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is [Form.Request](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Request)

i.e.

```
(function($){

    new Form.Request($('formID'), $('responseID'), {
        onSuccess : function() {
          //form submitted correctly
        }
    });

})(document.id);
```

where `$('formID')` is your form, and `$('responseID')` is the element that will hold the response (i.e. a response message)

Comment: Thank @stecb. I had to update the mootools.more library to get this work. I forgot that; so it took this much time. That was a nice tip.

Comment: Np, btw if u look at the documentation, u clearly find out that each plugin/feature is under the 'core' or 'more' tab ;)

Comment: Can we specify a submit button as in Prototype [parameters: form.serialize({submit: control.name})], if we have more than one submit buttons?